# Использование наследования Application для реализации зависимостей в Dagger2 в мультимодульном проекте

Tags: android, зависимости, dagger2

Здравствуйте, 
пишу андроид приложение в котором использую **Dagger2**. В данной библиотеке есть возможность назначать **custom scope** и потом используя

```
  public class MyApp extends Application
  { 
         ...
  }
```

можно создавать эти объекты с разным временем жизни, например в рамках одного **activity**, или в пределах нескольких **activity**.

Данная модель хорошо работает если у вас один модуль. Под модулем я подразумеваю модуль который создает **android studio** (у каждого модуля есть java файлы, ресурсные файлы, манифест файл)  (**Не** модуль который использует **dagger2**, **@Module** ) .

Но у меня мултимодульный проект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. есть общий модуль **Module1**, который в зависимости от ситуации подключает либо **Module2**, либо **Module3**, либо другой какой-нибудь модуль.

Проблема в том что к классу **MyApp** должны иметь доступ все модули чтобы
построить компонент интерфейса и в том же время класс **MyApp** должен иметь место ко всем модулям.

К примеру если **MyApp** объявить в **Module1** то:

1) Интерфейс компонента будет следующим

```
  @Singleton
  @Component(modules = {NetworkApiModule.class})

  public interface DiComponent {
     // to update the fields in your activities
     void inject(MainActivity2 activity); // 
  }
```

**MainActivity2** это класс обявленный в **Module2** тут все будет работать без проблем.

2) Далее **MyApp**:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
   DiComponent component;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     component = DaggerDiComponent.builder().build();
   }

   public DiComponent getComponent() {
      return component;
   }
```

}

Тут все тоже без проблем.

3) Далее нам нужно вводить зависимости к примеру в **MainActivity2** который находится в **Module2**:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

   @Inject NetworkApi networkApi;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ((MyApp) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);


   }
}
```

А вот здесь возникает проблема, как получить доступ к **MyApp** который находиться в **Module1**, если **MainActivity2** находится в **Module2**.

Т.е. в общем, класс **MyApp** должен находиться в каком нибудь из модулей и получается в одну сторону мы можем обеспечить доступ (**Module1->Module2**) а в другую уже нет (**Module2->Module1**) .

Как разрешить данную проблему ? Можно ли в данном случае что-то сделать ?

Заранее большое спасибо всем за ответы.